# topic.blade.php cannot fetch value->id, but it works with value->name

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I got the code snippet,

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="category-id-field">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category-id-field">
        <option value="" hidden disabled {{ $topic->id ? '' : 'selected' }}>Choose your category</option>
            @foreach ($categories as $value)
                @php
                  $selected = $topic->category_id === $value->id ? 'selected' : '';
                @endphp
        <option value="{{ $value->id }}" {{ $selected }}>{{ $value->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

And it shows like below, as you can see $value->name works but $value->id just shows up zero.

```html
<div class="form-group"><label for="category-id-field">Category</label> 
  <select name="category_id" id="category-id-field" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose your category</option> 
    <option value="0">statement</option> 
    <option value="0">life</option> 
    <option value="0">work</option> 
    <option value="0">study</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Versions:
laravel/framework: "^7.0"
Platform: macos catalina
mysql: 8.0.19

Some more background: 
Things I did, the id in the categories table used to be integer, I changed it to VARCHAR(30) and added it as the foreign key to table topics->category_id.

If anyone happens to have some experience on this one, please point out the error.  Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show your controller method ?

Comment: And why have you changed id to varchar ? any reason ?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, @Akhtar.  I made some effort and solved it.  1. Can you show your controller method? --The problem was lying in the app/Models/Category.php, something about Eloquent package; 2.why have you changed id to varchar ?  --It's actually quite implicit.  First, for the webpage itself we've foreseen the number of the categories would be less than 10. In addition, the reading language for the webpage would be chinese, so change the int primary key to readable english primary key is quite attemptable.

Comment: Okay brother it was good that you have solved by yourself and also shared some info.